# Why text attribute in SVG file does not appear in Android Studio vector asset XML on asset import

Tags: android, android-studio, svg

I imported an `.svg` file with the following xml in it

```
<text class="cls-4" transform="translate(3.08 8.71)">My Text</text>
<text class="cls-4" transform="translate(66.04 94.97) rotate(180)">My Text</text>
```

into Android Studio as an image asset via

```
File > New > Vector Asset
```

and in the xml of the new vector asset I do `ctrl+f` but find no string `My Text` and infact the text does not render becuase it does not exist in the svg file.

Answer (score 1):

I think the text attribute is somehow not interpreted by Android Studio. I was able to solve the problem by converting the text in the original Adobe Illustrator file to a path, then export the Illustrator file as an `svg` file, then import the `svg` image into Android studio as a vector asset; my problem was I was exporting the Illustrator file to `svg` format before converting the text to a path.

Steps for converting text to paths in Adobe Illustrator

http://reachheadwear.com/illustrator-101-creating-outlines

Answer (score -1):

So simple answer is you have to create path for text

Using InkScape  path/object to path

Done